# Can't get any results using query/rawquery #SQLite#

Tags: android, sqlite

When I use below code query database, I cannot get any result, but I can get results via sql command on console.

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(SampleActivity.this, "contents.db", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//Cursor cursor = db.query("ContentsTable", new String[] { "title" }, "id<10", null, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select title from ContentsTable", null);
db.close();
cursor.close();
```

I debug the program and found cursor's mCount=-1, and mStackTrace=DatabaseObjectNotClosedException after running db.rawquery(***), just like the photo showed:http://flic.kr/p/bw9P2o

Below is class DBHelper:
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "create table ContentsTable(id int, title varchar(100))";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        System.out.println("Update Database");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive the simple question but have you added rows yet?

**EDIT:**

You have to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` before accessing the data returned.

Comment: yes, because I can get results via sqlite3 commands(select title from ContentsTable) on console

Comment: Ok, close the cursor first then the db. Or better yet try using startManagingCursor() in your activity and never worry about closing it.

Comment: all info was got after running:  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select title from ContentsTable", null); no run db.close() or cursor.close();

Comment: this is probably better suited as a comment... not an answer

Comment: @AlexLockwood I agree, but don't have enough rep to comment on the question itself...

Comment: @Jake When I run db.close() before cursor.close() I am thrown a database not open exception. Give it a try otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: tried this but still cannot work, after all it can't get result, but not throw exception, whatever, thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Jake Oh dar, found it. You have to initialize the cursor with `cursor.moveToFirst()` after your query.

Comment: Hey Sam, WOW, you are so great, it works well now, thanks again for your greatest help*_*